# Get the text on the (Shape) I just used to execute the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code like below, then I assigned to a shape e.g. Rounded Rectangle1 with text inside it `RunMe` ,

```
Sub Caller_Text()
    MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

I need instead of the shape name to **get the text on that shape** I just used to execute the macro,

In advance, grateful for any useful comment and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt this as required:

```
ButtonName = Application.Caller
Set MyShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ButtonName)
MyString = ActiveSheet.Shapes(MyShape.Name).TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

Comment: You managed to answer this before me, testing this code produced a runtime error but altering the last line to:  `Mystring = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ButtonName)).TextFrame.Characters.Text` then worked for me.

Comment: @5202456 ,you are correct I got the same error, then I changed the code like you and now works

Comment: I had a typo in there. Now amended `MyShapeName` to `MyShape.Name`. No need for `Array`?

Comment: Yes now works correctly